# I want to open the Qliksense mobile app from another mobile application

Tags: react-native, qliksense

I have developed a mobile application in react-native and on click of a icon I want to open the Qliksense app which is installed in mobile

Answer (score 0):

Use `Linking` and the desired [app url scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app):

import Linking:
`import {Linking} from 'react-native';`

Then on your function/action you would like to open the other app:

```
const canOpenUrl = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);
if (canOcanOpenUrl) {
  Linking.openURL(url);
}
```

See more in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#canopenurl)

Comment: We found that to open any app there is a special parameter to open each app like to open mail parameter is mailto and for skype parameter is skype  then what parameter should we use for opening qliksense App

Comment: Is it possible to open the qliksense mobile app if we are having a web url like  "http://15.182.857.71:9000/sense/app/"

Comment: plz read the link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app